# BlueTooth Low Energy iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am connecting mac as a "Centerl" with my iPhone as a "Peripheral" using BlueTooth Low Energy.Both Peripheral and central connected successfully  and work in both mode foreground and background.

But my problem is that during background mode,if i manually on or off the bluetooth of my device, i dectected my blue tooth is off or on during background mode , but Central not connected with peripheral anymore during background mode.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable **Background Modes** for location update and for bluetooth low energy for your project target.

Select Xcode project properties >> project target >> Go to Capabilities >> Background Modes

[image]

As shown in above image check mark below properties:

1. Location Updates
2. Uses Bluetooth LE accessories

Edit:

Check device settings:

1. Check whether enable the background app refresh in Settings -> General -> Background App Refresh
2. Check whether enable the location service in Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services
3. Check whether enable the WiFi, even there not wifi signal.

If all above is enabled, but still not working, Try to reset the network settings in Settings -> General -> Reset or reboot the device.

Comment: Thanks for reply.Yes i also did this. But there's same issue.

Comment: my willRestoreState: is not working.I noticed now.any suggestion?

Comment: i followed your edited answer.Issue not solve.have you an example for background configuration for BLE? thanks

Comment: Right now. I don't have an example for BLE as like yours.  But I did create iBeacon demo in which I had some issues, and was able to solve by above solutions.